# How can I Extract information from HTML page using Python?

Tags: html, css, python-2.7

Based on the HTML page below, I am looking to extract this information about this property:

**1- Number of bathrooms**

**2- Living Area**

**3- Energy Rating**

**4- Description**

```
                <div class="bloco-imovel-resumo-dados">
                    <div id="Cpl_modulodadosresumidos_module_holder" class="modulo-dados-resumidos">

<h2 class="lbl_descricao_dados">Property Information</h2>

<ul class="bloco-dados">

    <li>
        <b>Condition:</b> <span>Renewed</span></li>
    <li>
        <b>Living Area:</b><span> 80 m<sup>2</sup></span></li>
    <li>
        <b>Total Area:</b><span> 0 m<sup>2</sup></span></li>
    <li>
        <b>Bathrooms:</b><span> 1 </span></li>
    <li>
        <b>Bedrooms:</b><span> 2 </span></li>
    <li>
        <b>Energy Rating:</b><span> C</span></li>

</ul>
```

```
                <div class="bloco-imovel-texto">
                    <h3 class="lbl_description">
                        Description </h3>
                    <p>At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident.Nam libero tempore, omnis dolor repellendus.</p>
                </div>
```

I tried to extract the number of bathrooms by writing the code below, but I have received this error `"AttributeError: 'HtmlElement' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_css_selector"`

```
from lxml import html,etree

with open(r'listing.html', "r") as f:

    page = f.read()

    tree = html.fromstring(page)

    Bathrooms = tree.find_element_by_css_selector('Bathrooms')

print('Bathrooms: {}'.format(tree.cssselect(Bathrooms)[0].text))
```

I am a beginner at HTML and CSS so I need your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 import lxml.html

    with open(r'listing.html', "r") as f:

        page = f.read()
        root=lxml.html.parse(page)
        object_list = root.xpath(".//div[@class='bloco-dado']")
        bathrooms = object_list[0]
        text=bathrooms.text_content()
 print(text)
```

Try this once, May this works

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, Banoth. I run this code and I have received this error "IndexError: list index out of range". I need really to your help to fix this error.

Comment: Can you check once what data is coming in the object_list ?

Comment: Data including photos, text and emails. I need your help, Banoth to fix this error.

Comment: is there any data in the object_list variable in my code? the error says that you are accessing the data which is not in the range.